# How to use data providers to create a test that runs before each test in a class?

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, codeception

I'm trying to test a class that handles a user's collection of favorite items, which can be of different types, eg. movies and songs.

So I have this base test class (I'm using Codeception, which uses Phpunit):

```
class BaseCollectionTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit {  

   public function setUp() : void {

      parent::setUp();

      $this->userId = $this->tester->createUser();     
      $this->tester->login( $this->userId ); 

   }
 
   public function dataProvider() {
      return [
         [ new CollectionService( "movies", $this->userId ) ],
         [ new CollectionService( "songs", $this->userId ) ]
      ]; 
   }

}
```

Now I want to test whether a user can rename an existing collection, so I would like to create a collection first before the renaming tests are executed. IDEALLY, I could do this:

```
class RenameCollectionTest extends BaseCollectionTest {

   protected $collection;
   protected $Service;

   /**
    * @dataProvider dataProvider
    */

   public function setUp( $Service ) : void {

      parent::setUp();

      $this->Service = $Service; 
      $this->collection = $this->Service->create_collection();
   
   }

   public function testRenamesCollection() {
      $renamedCollection = $this->Service->rename_collection( $this->collection["id"], "New Title" ); 
      $this->assertEquals( $renamedCollection["title"], "New Title" ); 
   }

}
```

However, I've read that data providers can't be used with `setUp`. So I've tried a bunch of workarounds, most notably this:

```
class RenameCollectionTest extends BaseCollectionTest {

   /**
    * @dataProvider dataProvider
    */
   public function testCreatesCollection( $Service ) {
      $this->Service = $Service; 
      return $this->Service->create_collection();
   }

   /**
    * @depends testCreatesCollection
    */
   public function testRenamesCollection( array $collection ) {
      $renamedCollection = $this->Service->rename_collection( $collection["id"], "New Title" ); 
      $this->assertEquals( $renamedCollection["title"], "New Title" ); 
   }

}
```

From what I've read, `testRenamesCollection` should receive the result of `testCreatesCollection` as its argument because of the `@depends` annotation, but I get a type error complaining that $collection received by `testRenamesCollection` is null and not an array (although I have verified that the return value of `testCreatesCollection` is in fact an array with the newly created collection data).

What other options do I have other than having to create a collection in each one of the renaming tests?

Comment: Really the only other option I can think of is to put the two tests together in the same function and raise your game on failure messages. But it seems like you've got a list of ways creation might fail, but do you really need to test renaming against each of those? Seems like renaming has its own, separate list of ways for things to go wrong. So maybe your renaming test starts with a simple creation step, ignoring all the permutations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need you first test (which doesn't assert anything ?)

Indeed you can't put any logic in dataproviders, the easiest way for me should be:

```
public function dataProvider() 
{
  return [
     [ "movies", $this->userId ],
     [ "songs", $this->userId ]
  ]; 
}

/**
 * @dataProvider dataProvider
 */
public function testCreatesAndRenamesCollection( $collectionName, $userId ) 
{
    $this->Service = new CollectionService( $collectionName, $userId ); 
    $collection = $this->Service->create_collection();
    $renamedCollection = $this->Service->rename_collection( $collection["id"], "New Title" ); 
    
    $this->assertEquals( $renamedCollection["title"], "New Title" ); 
}
```

(I would rather use simple properties in dataproviders to avoid duplicate code and have better maintanibility)

Comment: I have multiple renaming tests, in this way I would have to create the collection in each one of them, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid...